# Repeating an image within a SVG-Mask

Tags: svg

I'm currently generating the following SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <text id="txt1" y="100" font-weight="bold" font-family="Verdana" font-size="100" fill="white">Some Text</text>
        <image id="img1" x="0" y="0" width="425" height="319" opacity="1" xlink:href="http://designm.ag/images/0709/wood/71.jpg" />
    </defs>     
    <g id="group1" transform="translate(0 0) rotate(0)" opacity="1">
        <defs>
            <mask id="mask1" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                <use x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="400" transform="rotate(0)" opacity="1" xlink:href="#txt1" />
            </mask>
        </defs>
        <g mask="url(#mask1)" opacity="1">
            <use x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="400" transform="rotate(0) scale(1)" opacity="1" xlink:href="#img1" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

([Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/uS9ha/))

I've shorten the SVG and I know that there are two `defs`-blocks, but thats the result of the generation process done by the application I'm currently developing.

The problem is that the text is not fully visible, because the image-width is just 425px. Is there an easy way (e.g. an attribute) to repeat the image, that is used for the mask?

With a `scale` greater than 1 the text would be visible, but the image will be stretched and that's not what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in a number of different ways:

- Use a pattern fill (with the image you want) for the text (doesn't require masking)
- Use a pattern fill on a rectangle that uses a mask with the text in it

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RfD9L/1/) showing how to do a simple pattern.

The pattern definition:

```
<pattern patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="pat1" x="10" y="10" 
 width="425" height="319">
    <image width="425" height="319" 
     xlink:href="http://designm.ag/images/0709/wood/71.jpg" />
</pattern>
```

The usage of the above pattern:

```
<g mask="url(#mask1)" opacity="1">
    <rect width="1000" height="400" fill="url(#pat1)" />
</g>
```

And the [same but without using mask](http://jsfiddle.net/EAMmM/1/):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 viewBox="0 0 1000 360">
    <defs>
        <pattern patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="pat1" x="10" y="10" 
         width="425" height="319">
            <image width="425" height="319" 
             xlink:href="http://designm.ag/images/0709/wood/71.jpg" />
        </pattern>
        <text id="txt1" y="100" font-weight="bold" font-family="Verdana" 
         font-size="100">Some Text</text>
    </defs>     

    <use width="1000" height="400" xlink:href="#txt1" fill="url(#pat1)"/>
</svg>
```